# Corrupted php.ini (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been working on a Wordpress site that hasn't had any updates in many years and preparing it for a theme change as well.

After updating all plugins/Wordpress 5.2/PHP 7.2 everything seemed to be going well however the site has been experiencing intermittent crashing (it will work for awhile then it will crash for 5-10 minutes) [edit: The site crashing was probably not directly caused by the php.ini issue in retrospect]

Looking at the cpanel in the error logs I get the error:

```
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected TC_LABEL, expecting '=' in /home/website/public_html/php.ini on line 1 //sometimes it includes a referer
```

Running `php -i | grep php.ini`:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php
Loaded Configuration File => /opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php/php.ini
```

The php.ini (in `public_html`) contains the same repeated path many times (78,886 times according to my find and replace):

```
/opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718
```

Line 1:

```
/opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718[/opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718P/opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718H/opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718P/opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718]/opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718
```

I noticed that there was sometimes an extra character after `20170718`. I downloaded a local copy and did a find and replace and removed all instances of the path and what was left is a 'normal' php.ini (ie it's as if every `character` in the file was replaced with `path + character`)

[edit: Changing the public_html php.ini to php.ini_bk removes the error from cpanel logs]

Personal PS: Please note I am not a PHP nor Wordpress developer (typically I work in the MERN stack)

Comment: update your plugins and theme after backup . then rename file 
/home/website/public_html/php.ini
 and test if still same issue

Comment: all of the plugins are already updated fully and the theme is also at its latest version

Comment: Your php.ini should never be writable by the process that runs the web server and should not be located in (or under) the web server's document root directory. If your PHP code can change the contents of the php.ini then you have a serious security issue.

Comment: just rename php.ini to php.ini_bk file then check

Comment: PHP:  syntax error, unexpected TC_LABEL, expecting '=' in /home/website/public_html/php.ini on line 1 //sometimes it includes a referer...

error was in public_html root . check if its not hidden

Comment: @AlexHowansky the php.ini is currently located in `/home/mywebsite/public_html/php.ini` i think that is where it should be located no?

Comment: @lakshmanrajput I renamed the php.ini_bk. it did not fix the issue but now there is no error on the cpanel

Comment: _"i think that is where it should be located no?"_ Absolutely not. The public_html directory (and everything under it) should contain only things that you're willing to share with the world, like HTML, CSS, JS, and images. Configuration files, log files, PHP source code -- all that should be located elsewhere.

Comment: @AlexHowansky that makes sense. since this is a shared inmotion server wouldn't the php.ini be located outside of the files i have access to then (and any misconfigurations would be server wide and not related to the website itself?). Even though i haven't made any changes im now getting a `500 internal server error`. When i change the name of the php.ini I no longer have any errors showing in the cpanel logs however the `500 internal sever error` still persists

Comment: _"...and any misconfigurations would be server wide..."_ Possibly, depends on the server config. Still, even if you have a separate Apache setup per user account (so that each account can modify their config) then you should *still* have your php.ini outside the document_root and you should still make sure it's not writable.

Comment: @AlexHowansky running `php -i | grep php.ini` outputs `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php` and `Loaded Configuration File => /opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php/php.ini` so it doesnt appear to be using a different php.ini?

Comment: That looks good but something is amiss yet, as your posted error message indicates a failure while parsing `/home/website/public_html/php.ini`. It almost seems as if there's some code that's trying to execute that php.ini file as if it were PHP source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public_html is not the right place for php.ini

Can you do a

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

You have several options ... make a backup of your "old" php.ini first

- rebuild your PHP configuration
- download latest PHP
- Download PHP source and just copy php.ini template out of that

Sometimes it is better to do a clean install & import than updating a very old WordPress.

Regards Tom

Comment: where should the php.ini be? I see that the php.ini was modified the day that i updated wordpress from 4.x to 5.2

Comment: php.ini is usually located in /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini on apache . If you are using PHP FPM, it may be located in /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini or somewhere in a subdirectory of /etc/

Comment: Since this website is hosted on a shared inmotion server does this answer still apply as I assume that the php install and the php.ini would be the same for everyone?

Comment: also running `php -i | grep php.ini` outputs `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php` and
`Loaded Configuration File => /opt/imh/imh-php72/root/usr/lib/php/php.ini`

Comment: No, you should contact your hosting provider. I think it comes from a zend extension and a conflict with the settings in the php.ini in the webroot. One can do this to override the php settings, I would stick to this with php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php or set the php settings in a .htaccess file. Try to backup the file and remove it.

Comment: I think the only thing I would add to this answer is that not only is that the wrong place for php.ini but it can likely be removed/renamed if `php -i | grep php.ini` points to the 'right' php.ini especially on a shared host without access to that php.ini